# Windows - Perform Operations on File Dropped in Directory

Tags: automation, file-conversion

I am curious if the following is possible. I want to set up a special directory in which I drop a word file. A script/program (written by me) in the directory will detect a new file has been added and will then convert that word file to a PDF (save as/export word file as PDF), then convert that PDF to an excel spreadsheet and then put that final converted excel spreadsheet in some output directory. I have access to Adobe Acrobat Pro and all the MS Office suite.

This is what I want described in words. How easily achievable is this? Does this sort of thing exist? What is it called?

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you plan to convert PDF to XLSX? it would take a very special PDF to convert cleanly to excel.

Comment: Hey Frank, sorry about the delay. In Adobe Acrobat Pro there is a function that allows you to save as "spreadsheet" and it creates a nice (at least for my application) spreadsheet that is ready to be parsed or funneled into a database like MS Access.

Comment: ok. that will require you to find an API from adobe, or another PDF editor that supports the feature. Its beyond the scope of most APIs designed to manipulate PDF spec documents. that does make it a little more difficult, but if you can find a good library, its certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but you would have to write a program to do this. Windows does not have this kind of functionality built in, as you'd need to write a windows process that monitors the contents of the folder. The programming language you use needs to have libraries that do the conversion between Word and PDF and PDF and Excel. For example java does have some libraries like that. Writing such a program would require at least intermediate programming knowledge and you would need to spend a few days to make it work. As for the conversion itself, you could encounter problems the libraries not converting the way you expect them to between these formats that are really completely made for different purposes.

Comment: I see. I was hoping I could leverage built in functions through other programs like the "Save as" feature in Word to go from Word to PDF. And the "Export as Excel" feature in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: That can be done manually, but if you want it fully automated you somehow need a process that monitors the folder and starts the conversion when you drop the file. There might be some macro system that automates what you would do manually, but I don't know how you would bring the two parts 1) process watching the folder and 2) macro running to convert, together. It does not sound like an easy task.

Comment: Alright. Sounds like my best bet will be to do it manually then. Too bad but not a complete loss as I don't have an overwhelmingly large number of these things to do. Was just hoping I could work some programming into it. Maybe learn something new. Thanks anyways!